# Python Welsh-Powell graph coloring

Tags: python, graph, greedy, sat, graph-coloring

I have implemented algorithm for Welsh-Powell graph coloring.
Task is that you have txt document with lines of 2 numbers, in which the first one represent vertex and the second one represent its neighbor.
Looks like this:

```
1 2
1 4
1 5
1 8
1 9
1 11
2 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
2 7
2 8
2 10
2 11
2 12
3 4
3 5
3 6
3 7
3 8
3 9
3 11
4 6
4 9
4 10
4 11
4 12
5 6
5 7
5 10
5 11
5 12
6 7
6 10
6 11
6 12
7 8
7 10
7 11
7 12
8 10
8 11
8 12
9 10
9 12
10 12
```

Output should be also txt document with two numbers in line, where the first one is vertex and the second one is number of color like this:

```
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 3
6 4
7 5
8 3
9 1
10 2
11 6
12 6
```

The number of used colors is not important, as it shouldnt be more than all vertexes.

This is graphColoring.py

```
def file_to_graph(filename):
    file1 = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = file1.readlines()
    graph = [[], []]

    for line in lines:
        if line == '':
            continue

        row = line.split(' ')

        from_vertex = int(row[0])
        to_vertex = int(row[1])

        found_from_vertex = -1
        found_to_vertex = -1

        for i in range(len(graph[0])):
            if graph[0][i][0] == from_vertex:
                graph[0][i][1] += 1
                found_from_vertex = i

            if graph[0][i][0] == to_vertex:
                graph[0][i][1] += 1
                found_to_vertex = i

        if found_from_vertex == -1:
            graph[0].append([from_vertex, 1])

        if found_to_vertex == -1:
            graph[0].append([to_vertex, 1])

        graph[1].append((from_vertex, to_vertex))

    return graph


def get_color(colored_vertexes, vertex):
    for colored_vertex in colored_vertexes:
        if colored_vertex[0] == vertex:
            return colored_vertex[1]
    return -1


def color_graph(graph, max_colors=-1):
    sorted_vertexes = sorted(graph[0],  key=lambda x: x[1])
    colored_vertexes = []
    for vertex_with_edges in reversed(sorted_vertexes):
        colored_vertexes.append([vertex_with_edges[0], 0])

    actual_color = 1

    while True:
        for vertex_with_edge_count in reversed(sorted_vertexes):
            color = 0
            colored_vertex_index = -1
            vertex_name = vertex_with_edge_count[0]

            for i in range(len(colored_vertexes)):
                if colored_vertexes[i][0] == vertex_name:
                    color = colored_vertexes[i][1]
                    colored_vertex_index = i
                    break

            if color != 0:
                continue

            color_of_neighbours = []

            for (from_vertex, to_vertex) in graph[1]:
                if from_vertex == vertex_name:
                    color_of_neighbours.append(get_color(colored_vertexes, to_vertex))

                if to_vertex == vertex_name:
                    color_of_neighbours.append(get_color(colored_vertexes, from_vertex))

            if actual_color not in color_of_neighbours:
                colored_vertexes[colored_vertex_index][1] = actual_color

        actual_color += 1
        is_colored = True
        for colored_vertex in colored_vertexes:
            if colored_vertex[1] == 0:
                is_colored = False
                break

        if is_colored:
            break

    return colored_vertexes
```

And this is main.py

```
from graphColoring import file_to_graph, color_graph
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph = file_to_graph(sys.argv[1])
    colored_vertexes = color_graph(graph)
    for colored_vertex in sorted(colored_vertexes, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        print(str(colored_vertex[0]) + " " + str(colored_vertex[1]))
```

EDIT//: I received a solution for problem with input, but I dont have expected output. Instead of expected output above, i received this:

```
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 4
5 6
6 5
7 4
8 5
9 1
10 3
11 3
12 2
```

//
I should use "python main.py ./input.txt" to input txt document, but after running the program it says:

```
line 7, in <module>
    graph = file_to_graph(sys.argv[1])
                          ~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I˙m not so good at programming and all of this is really hard for me to understand so I really appreciate some help to make this functional.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working. And it also gives your desired output

```
1 1
2 2
3 1
4 2
```

I think it is about how you run the script. Because when I run
`python .\main.py` I also get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fhdwnig\Desktop\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    graph = file_to_graph(sys.argv[1])
                          ~~~~~~~~^^^
```

you have to run it like this:
`python .\main.py .\input.txt`
(on windows)

The script is missing the input file.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
sorted_vertexes = sorted(graph[0],  key=lambda x: x[1])
```

to this one

```
sorted_vertexes = sorted(sorted(graph[0][::-1],key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True),  key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: But why? Please elaborate. How do you interpret the problem as a mere sorting order problem?

Comment: I knew that the sorting method is right, so the only mix up that could have happened is with nodes that have an equal number of connections but the node order is  random (file to graph algorithm does not sort them) but he found the the colors by looking from smallest to biggest, btw the -1 in graph[0][::-1] is not needed, idk why i added it. 

Sorry for the late reply i don't usually use stack overflow. you probably don't even remember what this post is about by now.